# use keyBy method inside with method in eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I want use keyBy method inside of with method in Eloquent. like this:

```
$settings = $settings->with(
    array('languages' => function($query)
    {
        $query->get()->keyBy('languages_language_id');
    })
)->get()->keyBy('setting_key');
```

How can i do that? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly in the `with` Clause, instead you can override the collection with the `keyBy` version:

```
foreach ($settings as $keySetting => $setting)
{
    $settings[$keySettings]->languages = $settings[$keySettings]->languages->keyBy('languages_language_id');
}
```

As you can se you still have to iterate over the results and reorder one by one. This is just a cleaner version using `keyBy` of what you are doing already.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i use this:

```
$settings = $settings->with('languages')->get()->keyBy('setting_key')->toArray();
foreach ($settings as $keySetting => $setting)
{
    $languages = $setting['languages'];
    $settings[$keySetting]['languages'] = array();
    foreach ($languages as $lang)
    {
        $settings[$keySetting]['languages'][$lang['languages_language_id']] = $lang;
    }
}
```